# Setting 2 fonts with different sizes in MacVim

Tags: vim, macvim

I'm using Vim in MacVim on Mac OS X. I have following config in .gvimrc:

```
set guifont=Inconsolata:h15
```

But I'd like to set to different font and font size for non-ASCII symbols (because Inconsolata didn't have russian symbols).

Problem is that Inconsolata id visually a lot smaller, than Monaco that I'd like to to use for russian characters.

In iTerm 2 I have following preferences:

1. Regular font: 15px Inconsolata
2. Non-ASCII Font: 12pt Monaco

I'd tried to use:

```
set guifont=Inconsolata:h15,Monaco:h12
```

But :h12 part didn't work (while Monaco part worked). Is there a way to fix it?

Answer (score 0):

You can have a look at `:set guifontset=-*-*-medium-r-normal--16-*-*-*-c-*-*-*`

From `:h guifontset`:

> When not empty, specifies two (or more) fonts to be used.  The first
>   one for normal English, the second one for your special language.  See
>   |xfontset|