# Varying font size in gvim windows

Tags: vim, nerdtree

Can I make the font size in my `NERDTree` window smaller than in all other windows of gvim?

Generally I need large font size of 15 but I'd like the folder tree window of `NERDTree` to be 12 - is this possible to set using code in `_vimrc`. Currently I have the following simple setting:

```
set guifont=Consolas:h16:cANSI
```

---

Slightly duplicated question and answered here:

1. [Stackoverflow Post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11354601/vim-different-font-size-in-each-split)
2. [Stackoverflow Post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11330984/setting-2-fonts-with-different-sizes-in-macvim)

Comment: That's impossible, unfortunately.

Comment: Duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/q/11354601 and http://stackoverflow.com/q/11330984.

Comment: @glts - you are correct - I'll leave the question anyhow as it refers to NERDTree - just in case anyone searches specifically for that in the future: thanks for help.

Comment: possible duplicate of [VIM: different font size in each split](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11354601/vim-different-font-size-in-each-split)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not possible bro. Vim uses the same font size for all its windows.
This is one (if not the only :D) limitation of Vim.