# Can you set different fonts for different file types in gvim?

Tags: vim, fonts

For example source code pro for .py files and ubuntu font for .txt files

Comment: No, you can't use more than one font in a Vim instance.

Comment: Same as [VIM: different font size in each split](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11354601) or [Setting 2 fonts with different sizes in MacVim](http://stackoverflow.com/q/11330984) and [Varying font size in gvim windows](http://stackoverflow.com/q/16624981).

Comment: But if you've only got one file or filetype open at a time, I'd imagine you'd be able to use a filetype autocmd or something like that to switch fonts by filetype.

Comment: possible duplicate of [VIM: different font size in each split](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11354601/vim-different-font-size-in-each-split)

Answer (score 4):

No, at least not where two different fonts are displayed simultaneously (e.g. when you have both a Python and text file open in two window splits). You can dynamically switch the entire global `'guifont'` option triggered by `:autocmd`s, though.

The reason for that is that Vim / GVIM adhere to a *classic terminal model*, where the entire screen consists of fixed-width display cells. Different fonts, due to their different size properties, would either look very ugly or disrupt that fixed cell model.

Answer (score 1):

As others have pointed out, you can't have multiple fonts in the same instance of gvim (the same desktop window) at the same time.  But if you're opening a new gvim for each different type of file, then you can do it with autocommands, specifically something like:

`autocmd FileType python setlocal guifont=<font>`

Replace `<font>` with whatever font you want (you can check `set guifont?` to get the formatting right).

YMMV if you use a lot of buffers, tabs, etc.  But personally, I can't think of a time (other than :help) when I have two different filetypes open simultaneously.

Answer (score 0):

Check out the following recent discussion in vim-use groups. There it is claimed that it is possible to change font based on syntax:

[vim-use-thread](https://groups.google.com/d/msg/vim_use/VmZJl_jbtI4/5RRW-vVjE68J)